# Adding live functionality to dynamically added element in jQuery

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I make an element in jQuery plugin:

```
this.addButton = $("<a>", {
                   text: "ADD",
                   "class": "addButton"
                }).appendTo(this.element);
```

Then i add live functionality:

```
this.addButton.live("click", function() {
            that.somefunction("addSomething");
        });
```

And it isn't working.

IF i change "live" to "bind" it works OR when i do:

```
$('.addButton').live("click", function() {
     that.somefunction("addSomething");
});
```

it works too. But why adding live to an dynamically added element doesn't work?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`live()` needs to examine the event on a parent element to work. The way you have set it up, the event can not propagate to any parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) works:

> The .live() method is able to affect elements that have not yet been
>   added to the DOM through the use of event delegation: a handler bound
>   to an ancestor element is responsible for events that are triggered on
>   its descendants. The handler passed to .live() is never bound to an
>   element; instead, .live() binds a special handler to the root of the
>   DOM tree. In the example above, when the new element is clicked, the
>   following steps occur: A click event is generated and passed to the
>    for handling. No handler is directly bound to the , so the
>   event bubbles up the DOM tree. The event bubbles up until it reaches
>   the root of the tree, which is where .live() binds its special
>   handlers by default. 
>   * As of jQuery 1.4, event bubbling can optionally stop at a DOM
>   element "context". The special click handler bound by .live()
>   executes. This handler tests the target of the event object to see
>   whether it should continue. This test is performed by checking if
>   $(event.target).closest(".clickme") is able to locate a matching
>   element. If a matching element is found, the original handler is
>   called on it. Because the test in step 5 is not performed until the
>   event occurs, elements can be added at any time and still respond to
>   events.

lives doesn't bind an event to an object, it attach a listener to the window and then when the events bubble ups it checks for the original target. So you don't add it to the new object.